# Ubuntu 22.04 black screen after NVIDIA update

Tags: boot, nvidia, 22.04, tty, virtual-console

I only have Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop. I tried to update NVIDIA drivers since Pytorch won't see CUDA on my laptop. I installed it and then decided to re-boot my device. Now I have a black screen with peeping white underscore like in virtual terminal.
As other solutions suggested I tried to access tty1 using alt+ctrl+f1(f1 through f6) nothing is showing up. And because I did not set up my GRUB before holding `shift` would be pointless
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that purging all Nvidia drivers, and then reverting to 525 instead of 535, helps. Granted, this prevents certain games from being played, but it will at least restore functionality. Just make sure you purge only the drivers and not the packages, as Ubuntu has dependency on those.